# Lag on Game Generation

Tags: android, android-asynctask, render

I have this game and it truly requires a load of item generation so I have it all being handled in an AsyncTask however this class is taking an extremely long time to execute sometimes while other times it take miliseconds...  What is causing this to sometimes be fast and sometimes slow?

```
public class handleStuff extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>
    {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            Random r = new Random();
            if(r.nextInt(200) == 0 && clouds.size() <= 6)
            {
                Cloud c = new Cloud(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, cloudBM1.getWidth(), cloudBM2.getHeight());
                clouds.add(c);
            }
            for(int i = clouds.size() - 1; i > -1; i--) 
            {
                Cloud tempC = clouds.get(i);
                if(tempC.x <= 0 - cloudBM1.getWidth() && tempC.dir == 0)
                    clouds.remove(i);
                if(tempC.x >= SCREEN_WIDTH && tempC.dir == 1)
                    clouds.remove(i);
            }
            if(System.currentTimeMillis() - lastESpawn >= 750)
            {
                Enemy x = new Enemy(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, enemy.getWidth(), enemy.getHeight());
                enemies.add(x);

                lastESpawn = System.currentTimeMillis();
            }
            for(int i = enemies.size() - 1; i > -1; i--) 
            {
                Enemy tempE = enemies.get(i);
                if(tempE.x <= 0 - enemy.getWidth())
                    enemies.remove(tempE);
            }
            for(int i = 0; i < enemies.size(); i++)
            {
                Enemy tempE = enemies.get(i);
                if(System.currentTimeMillis() - tempE.lastBulletSpawn >= 800 && tempE.x <= SCREEN_WIDTH)
                {
                    EnemyBullet eb = new EnemyBullet(tempE.x, tempE.y, enemyBullet.getWidth(), enemyBullet.getHeight(), enemy.getWidth(), enemy.getHeight());
                    enemyBullets.add(eb);

                    tempE.lastBulletSpawn = System.currentTimeMillis();
                }
            }
            for(int i = bullets.size() - 1; i > -1; i--) 
            {
                Bullet tempB = bullets.get(i);
                if(tempB.x >= SCREEN_WIDTH)
                    bullets.remove(i);
            }
            for(int i = enemyBullets.size() - 1; i > -1; i--) 
            {
                EnemyBullet tempEB = enemyBullets.get(i);
                if(tempEB.x <= 0 - enemyBullet.getWidth())
                    enemyBullets.remove(i);
            }
            if(System.currentTimeMillis() - lastPBSpawn >= 400)
            {
                Bullet b = new Bullet(x, y, player.getWidth(), player.getHeight());
                bullets.add(b);

                lastPBSpawn = System.currentTimeMillis();
            }
            for(int i = explosions.size() - 1; i > -1; i--) 
            {
                Explosion tempEx = explosions.get(i);
                tempEx.update();
                if(tempEx.duration <= 0)
                    explosions.remove(i);
            }
            initial_load = true;
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, nobody likes debugging and I bet no one will make the tests themselves. That is up to you. So what you do is you log how long an operation takes. That is very easy. Some example code.

```
public class HandleStuffJob extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
    private long mTime;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        startLogging();

        try {
            doSomeFancyStuff();
        }

        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        stopLogging();

        return null;
    }

    private void startLogging() {
        mTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    private void doSomeFancyStuff() throws InterruptedException {
        /*
         * For this demonstration I will just sleep the thread and pretend it to
         * do some work.
         */

        Thread.sleep(1234);
    }

    private void stopLogging() {
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();

        Log.d("Test", "The operation took " + (now - mTime) + " milliseconds or " + ((now - mTime) / 1000) + " seconds.");
    }
}
```

And **please** only use Upper Case characters for class names.